# What is the meaning of "It spoke to him of sausage" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "It spoke to him of sausage" in the following sentence(Source: The truffle pig by Claire Huchet. Wiese, Kurt, Bishop )

> Pierre loved to shake his piggy bank. **It spoke to him of sausage**
>   roasted on a fork over the open fire.

Does "It spoke to him of sausage" mean "It spoke to him and It spoke of sausage" or "Sausage spoke to him"?

Does it mean "That sausage roasted on a fork over the open fire spoke to him"
or "That Pierre loved to shake his piggy bank spoke to him. and that Pierre loved to shake his piggy bank spoke of sausage"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the *sound of shaking the piggy bank* resembled to that of sausage being roasted on a fork over the open fire. Yes, Pierre is a kid and a kid can think of anything! :)

Roasting and frying food create a sound. Funnily, [I tried to hear one!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8cBDfqXaW4)